# jquery issue with mouseenter mouseleave on hover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseenter

I'm having an issue with jquery mouseenter / mouseleave on element hover where stuff continually flickers. So it kinda works, but it flickers.

Here is the code I have (on ready):

```
myLinkElement.bind({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("empty");
        $(this).parent().addClass("waiting");
        $(this).parent().find("#waitingText").html("hello");
        myContainerOverlay.stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("empty");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("waiting");
        $(this).parent().find("#waitingText").html("");
        myContainerOverlay.stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem, and tell us what browser(s) you've tried this with.

Comment: Post some HTML with that or event better do a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) showcasing your issue.

Comment: Is mkLinkElement text or an inline block? In other words what is the CSS display setting. I have seen this when you are putting it on text that isn't set as a block or inline-block because the class modifies the text and now the mouse is not exactly over a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion, but whitout a fiddle or any html it's hard to say if it will work, it depends on how the classes and visibility of the elements are initially set etc:

```
myLinkElement.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('empty waiting').find("#waitingText").html("hello");
        myContainerOverlay.fadeToggle();        
});​
```

Or a different approach:

```
myLinkElement.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var state = e.type=='mouseenter';
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('empty waiting')
           .find("#waitingText").html(state?"hello":"");
    myContainerOverlay[state?'fadeIn':'fadeOut']();
});​
```